# TS2322: Type 'Product[] | null' is not assignable to type 'Product[]' в чем проблема?

Tags: typescript, angular

Интерфейс

```
export interface Product {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  price: number;
  imageURL: string;
}
```

И компонент

```
products: Product[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.sendGetRequest().pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe((res: HttpResponse<Product[]>)=>{
      console.log(res);
      this.products = res.body; // Ошибка в этом месте
    })
  }
```

При компиляции выдает ошибку:

```
TS2322: Type 'Product[] | null' is not assignable to type 'Product[]'.   Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Product[]'.
```

Как ее исправить?

Comment: менять возвращаемый тип `sendGetRequest`

Comment: Поменяйте объявление `products: Product[] = [];` на это `products?: Product[];`. Или, перед присваиванием = res.body делайте проверку `if (res && res.body) {...`

Comment: products?: Product[]; не помог, а if (res && res.body) { помогло

Comment: Если вы уверены, что в теле ответа будет всегда массив, то можете после `.body` поставить восклицательный знак. Так TypeScript будет понимать, что значение не может быть `null` или `undefined`.